# Node.js mssql parameterized query not working with ALTER LOGIN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js

I'm trying to alter someones login using mssql and parameterized queries, but I keep getting an error when I try to run this:

```
    var request = new sql.Request(connection);
    request.input('thepassword', sql.VarChar, newpass);

    request.query('ALTER LOGIN ' + user + ' WITH PASSWORD = @thepassword' ,function(err, recordset){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            callback(false);
        }
        else{
            callback(true);
        }
    });
```

'newpass' is a string passed in through a function paramter. The error I keep getting is this:

```
RequestError: Incorrect syntax near '@thepassword'.
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Do you mean `UPDATE` instead of `ALTER`?

Comment: No, I'm trying to use the ALTER LOGIN command.

Comment: Does `@thepassword` need to be surrounded with `'`?

Comment: I've tried that aswell and i get a different error. It also shouldnt have to be surrounded by ' because its already of type VarChar

Comment: What happens when you run the interpolated sql statement directly?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Grab the actual sql that your code is generating and run it against the db yourself instead of letting the app do it. Hopefully you will get the same error. Otherwise the library is the problem.

Comment: Oh it works perfectly fine without the parameterized query, changes the password and everything. It just fails when i try to use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: which package are you using? https://github.com/Azure/node-sqlserver?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

Comment: For what it's worth, I have the exact same problem with "alter login" on SQL Server, but through the PHP PDO interface. I can only speculate that there's something unusual about how an "alter login" statement is processed, since parameters work exactly as expected in other statements. Thankfully my use case is in controlled circumstances, where I don't feel too bad about giving up and just inserting the strings into the SQL. Something tells me that having seen this go unanswered for 6 years may be the closest thing to validation that I'm going to get.